Spark sql pivot with all column values in for loop
I am pivoting a view in Spark  as decribed below
create view default.vw_sells(report_date,load_time,Region,`brand`,`sum_value` ) as 
(select report_date,load_time,Region,`brand`,sum(`value`) as `value` from default.hub_sgsbi_dbo_splusorders group by report_date,load_time,Region,`brand` order by report_date desc,load_time desc, Region asc,`brand` asc);

I need to pivot above view, I have tried below but it gives exception in beeline
select * from vw_sells
PIVOT (
        SUM(`sum_value`) AS sum FOR `brand` in (select distinct `brand` from vw_sells)
    );

If I define the values in loop explicitly, it would have no error
select * from vw_sells
PIVOT (
        SUM(`sum_مبلغ سفارش اولیه بدون مالیات`) AS sum FOR `brand` in ('b','c')

